# How to consume external MongoDB service in Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, typescript, kubernetes

I have been setting up a Kubernetes cluster for my work deployment. I have my MongoDB hosted on an external droplet and want to configure external service access.

I am following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services).
When I apply the my configuration with kubectl everything seems to be running fine.

My setup service & Endpoint

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: mongo
spec:
 ports:
 - name: mongodb
   port: xxxx
------
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: mongo
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: 159.89.x.x
   ports:
     - port: xxx
```

I am developing using typescript and this is how I currently set up my DB connection

```
const MONGO_URI = `mongodb://${config.mongourl}:${config.mongoport}/${config.collection}?authSource=admin`;
 const options ={
    user:`${config.mngusername}`, 
    pass:`${config.mngpassword}`,
    keepAlive: true, 
    keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
 }
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, options);
```

My question is, how do I consume the setup service/deploymentsin my code.

**thanks**

Comment: Are you asking how to access the service from your cluster? If so, you can simply use the service name: mongodb://mongo:port

Comment: mongo seems to be undefined, the pods start but always trying to connect to default suing default MongoDB settings

Comment: I have a very similar setup, with an endpoint/service pointing to an external mongodb server, and this is how I did it. You might want to check if the name is visible to the pods by executing some name lookups from within the pods.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to consume an external service, such as:

1. Hardcoding the IP:Port of the service in your app.
2. Using environment variables in your app and injecting them through [configmaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).
3. Creating a service/endpoint, [ExternalName](http://EXTERNAL_MYSQL_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST) service, or a service with [External IPs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips). This allows your applications to use
   Kubernetes' [Service Discovery](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#discovering-services) mechanisms.

In your case you can just use:
 `const MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://mongo/${config.collection}?authSource=admin';`
as the name `mongo` will be mapped to `159.89.x.x:xxx`

Comment: I would love for it to be a simple as the last solution  but $mongo still seems to be undefined

Comment: Are you trying to access `$mongo`, or `mongo`? With that service setup, `mongo` should be available.

Comment: I got it wrong. It is mongo and not $mongo. Anyway, is you application in the same namespace as the Service (default)? You can try using `mongo.default` instead. You can also try using the environment variables: $MONGO_SERVICE_HOST and $MONGO_SERVICE_PORT. To debug the DNS you can go inside your pod and try `curl mongo`

Comment: I don't think you can use service External IPs for this issue. According to the doc(https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips) external IPs are meant for exposing k8 svc for clients with some specific IPs.